# How to emit and disconnect sockets in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

In onchange I am opening a socket and i can able to emit and fetch data. but on any event a new socket is opened.

Withoutopening a new socket i need to emit data from the same socket Id.

May i know what i am doing wrong

In _dashboardStoreChange I was opening a socket and i can able connect to a socket and emit and i am able to get socket data.

on showfilter function i am having an event, on that event I want to emit fetch_graph_data alone, But new socket is getting opened and cannot able to emit with first socket data. both socket data is coming as 2 sockets is opened i want to emit from the first socket.

While disconnecting a socket a new socket is getting opened instead of closing the old opened socket so always onw socket is opened all the time

```
     import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';  
       import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

  class UpdateDashboard extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     };
    this._dashboardStoreChange = this._dashboardStoreChange.bind(this);


}

componentWillMount() {
   DashboardStore.on('change', this._dashboardStoreChange);


}

componentWillUnmount() {
    DashboardStore.removeListener('change', this._dashboardStoreChange);



    let ns = '/dashboard';
    let access_token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
    let user_id = localStorage.getItem("connected_socket_id");
    let query_data = {access_token : access_token};
    const socket = socketIOClient('http://0.0.0.0:9000'+ns,{query:query_data});

    let disconnect_query_data = {access_token : access_token, socket_id: user_id}
    socket.emit('disconnect_socket', disconnect_query_data);
}
componentDidMount() {
  DataConnectionAction._getDataSourcesList();

}




_dashboardStoreChange(type){
  if (type == 'SingleDashboard') {
        let singledashboard = DashboardStore._getSingleDashboard() || {};
        this.setState({ singledashboard }, ()=>{
          localStorage.setItem("dashboardIdforloadchart", this.state.singledashboard.data.dashboard_id);
          this.setState({
            dashboard_id: this.state.singledashboard.data.dashboard_id,


          }, ()=>{
            let ns = '/dashboard';
            let access_token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");

            let query_data = {access_token : access_token};


            const socket = socketIOClient('http://0.0.0.0:9000'+ns,{query:query_data});
             socket.on("connection_data", data => this.setState({ socketresponse: data }, ()=>{
              localStorage.setItem("connected_socket_id", this.state.socketresponse.connected_socket_id);
              console.log(this.state.socketresponse);



                  let chart_query_data = {"access_token":access_token, 'socket_id' : this.state.socketresponse.connected_socket_id, dashboard_id: this.state.dashboard_id}
                    socket.emit('fetch_graph_data', chart_query_data);


                    socket.on('fetch_data_ack', data => this.setState({response: data}, ()=>{

                    }));
                    socket.on('dashboard_data', data => this.setState({response: data}, ()=>{
                      var layout = this.generateLayout(this.state.response.data.length, this.state.response);
                      this.setState({layout});
                    }));
            }));









          });

        });

     }

}




generateLayout(chartCount,layoutObj) {

  console.log("generateLayout",chartCount, layoutObj);
    var layout = [], y, i;

    if(layoutObj && layoutObj.dashboard_layout!=null)
    {
     var keysArr=[];
     Object.keys(layoutObj.dashboard_layout)
      .forEach(function eachKey(key) { 
      keysArr.push(key);
     });


    for (i = 0; i <= chartCount - 1; i++) {
      y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      layout[i] = {x:layoutObj.dashboard_layout[keysArr[i]].x, y:layoutObj.dashboard_layout[keysArr[i]].y, w: layoutObj.dashboard_layout[keysArr[i]].w, h: layoutObj.dashboard_layout[keysArr[i]].h, minW: 2, maxW: 6, minH:10, maxH: 100, isResizable: true, isDraggable: true, i: i.toString()};
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (i = 0; i <= chartCount - 1; i++) {
       y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
     layout[i] = {x: i * 2 % 12, y: Math.floor(i / 6) * y, w: 2, h: 6, minW: 2, maxW: 6, minH:6, maxH: 100, isResizable: true, isDraggable: true, i: i.toString()};
     }


  }
   return {lg:layout};

}


showFilter(ds_id, index, bardata1){


  let xname = this.state.response.data[index].axis_details.x;
  let value = bardata1.variable;
  this.setState({
    filterClickData: [{
          condition: "equals",  
          value:value ,
          field_name:xname
    }]
  }, ()=>{

    let data = {
        dashboard_name: this.state.dashboardName,
        dashboard_layout: this.state.response.dashboard_layout,
        graphs: this.state.singledashboard.data.graphs,
        filter_definitions: [
          {
            "ds_id": ds_id,
            "filter_obj": this.state.filterClickData
          }
        ],
        "created_by": localStorage.getItem("user_id")
      }

       DashboardAction._UpdateDashboard(data, (data)=>{


         let ns = '/dashboard';
          let access_token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
          let user_id = localStorage.getItem("connected_socket_id");
          let query_data = {access_token : access_token};
          const socket = socketIOClient('http://0.0.0.0:9000'+ns,{query:query_data});

            socket.on("connection_data", data => this.setState({ socketresponse: data }, ()=>{
              localStorage.setItem("connected_socket_id", this.state.socketresponse.connected_socket_id);
              let chart_query_data = {"access_token":access_token, 'socket_id' : this.state.socketresponse.connected_socket_id, dashboard_id: this.state.dashboard_id}
                    socket.emit('fetch_graph_data', chart_query_data);


                    socket.on('fetch_data_ack', data => this.setState({response: data}, ()=>{

                    }));
                    socket.on('dashboard_data', data => this.setState({response: data}, ()=>{


                      var layout = this.generateLayout(this.state.response.data.length, this.state.response);
                      this.setState({layout});
                    }));
            }));
      })


  });




}


_loadSavedChart(){
    return (
      <ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
      {this.state.response && this.state.response.data && this.state.response.data.map((data, i) => 
        <Paper id='resizer' key={i} className="paper_panel">{this._renderChart(data)}
         </Paper>
      )} 
      </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
     )

  }

render() {


    return (

       <div>
            <div>
                <section className="content_block">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="row dashboard_list">
                          <div>{this._loadSavedChart()}</div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>





        </div>

    );
}
 }

export default UpdateDashboard;
```

Expecting to open only 1 socket, on showFilter event I want to emit data from the same socket opened first, instead of opening a new socket.

Comment: may i know where  need to write

Comment: can you tell in which life cycle and how can i create seperately

Comment: I would write a simple class that is not a React component and that maintains its own state. I would `import` and use that class as a Singleton so your entire application has access to the single socket connection. This would be the simplest approach.

Comment: can you give that class

Comment: please let me know on event without creating socket how  can emit fetch data alone

Comment: When I get some time today I'll write something up for you,

Comment: no feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, connect once during component mounting, not on every change. And disconnect upon unmounting. Then, only send data during the change event.

I have modified the standard TODO demo app from the React web site to include the use of WebSockets and to transmit each TODO item to the WebSocket server. I am using the websocket.org echo server, so everything sent simply comes back.

Set up the WebSocket Client and prepare to respond to Socket stuff:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // Socket Related Events
    document.addEventListener("socket-open", this.handleSocket);
    document.addEventListener("socket-closed", this.handleSocket);
    document.addEventListener("socket-receive", this.handleSocket);
    document.addEventListener("socket-send", this.handleSocket);
    document.addEventListener("socket-error", this.handleSocket);
    Socket.setUrl(/* to something */);
    Socket.init();
  }
```

Don't forget to disconnect:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    Socket.close();
  }
```

Now the bit about reacting to a change. Each time a TODO item is "submitted", the Component state is updated with the new TODO. This is the ideal place to send the new item. So the last line of the `onSubmit` handler is this:

```
Socket.send(JSON.stringify(newItem));
```

The working version of this app can be found in the React Live editor here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/randycasburn/ReactWebSocketTODO/tree/master/

And can be downloaded from GitHub here:

https://github.com/randycasburn/ReactWebSocketTODO/tree/master/